# Opacity transition affecting background color of adjacent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am revealing an element using a CSS transition that is triggered by a JavaScript scroll event however this transition is affecting the background color of an adjacent element in Safari (5.1.7) and Chrome (27.0.1453.93) on a Mac (10.6.8) which makes no sense at all. I think I have stumbled upon a bug.

I duplicated the issue in Safari only using the following, stripped-down code and created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5AEMF/) but the issue does not occur within that framework:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Opacity transition affecting color of adjacent element</title>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#bar {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

#content {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 9999px;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#content.scrolled {
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var scrolled = false;

var init = function() {
    onScroll(null);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
};

var onScroll = function(e) {
    if (window.scrollY > 0 && !scrolled) {
        scrolled = true;
        document.getElementById('content').className = 'scrolled';
    } else if (window.scrollY === 0 && scrolled) {
        scrolled = false;
        document.getElementById('content').removeAttribute('class');
    }
};

window.addEventListener('load', init);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder if there's a workaround for this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A byproduct of hardware acceleration I guess. Even though the transitioning element has no backface visibility.

Comment: i cant see any bug. which elements bg color is affected? You could try jquery animation, instead of css transition.

Answer (score 0):

Use colors in RGB form eg: `color:rgba(255, 106, 0, 0.24)` the last parameter in this property 0.24 is an opacity. make it 0 and it will be transparent.